# finding maximum & minimum number from 2 numbers in an array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the maximum and minimum numbers out of 2 integers that a user has inputted.
Firstly i have converted the string to int, then went to put them into an array so i can manipulate them. I think i'm getting stuck when it comes to assigning variables to an array. But i couldn't see any examples of arrays with variables assigned to them, which is probably where i'm going wrong.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string txtbxnum1 = Int32.Parse(num1);
       string txtbxnum2 = Int32.Parse(num2);

       int[] numbers = new int[2] {0,1};
       int numbers [0] = num1;
       int numbers [1] = num2;

       int maximumNumber = Max.numbers();
       int minimumNumber = Min.numbers();
       MessageBox.Show (maximumNumber.Text);
    }
```

I would be glad of any help or direction.

Comment: Do the numbers have to go into an array? Otherwise it's one statement: `maximumNumber = Math.Max(txtbxnum1, txtbxnum2);`

Comment: This code is all wrong,it seems like you should read first few chapters of some introductory c# book.

Answer (score 7):

If all you have is two numbers, you do not need an array: [`System.Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx) provides functions to find the smaller and the larger of two numbers, called `Math.Max` and `Math.Min`.

```
// Int32.Parse takes a string, and returns an int, not a string:
int n1 = Int32.Parse(num1);
int n2 = Int32.Parse(num2);
// Math.Min and Math.Max functions pick the min and max
int min = Math.Min(n1, n2);
int max = Math.Max(n1, n2);
// Show both numbers in a message box in one go using String.Format:
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Min:{0} Max:{1}", min, max));
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit messed up syntax. Your code is **not** `C#` language valid code.

You have to do something like this:

```
var numbers = new int[]{0,1,567,4,-5,0,67....};
```

and max/min is simply like

```
var maximum = numbers.Max();
var minimum = numbers.Min();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` both of which accept two integers as arguments.

Let me know if that is not sufficient detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
int maximumNumber = Math.Max(numbers[0],numbers[1]);
int minimumNumber = Math.Min(numbers[0],numbers[1]);

MessageBox.Show(maximumNumber + " " is the largest and " + minimumNumber + " is the smallest");
```

That said you shouldn't really access the array values like that, but it'll work for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your interaction with the TextBoxes and strange parsing and then setting to a string, but assuming num1 and num2 are integers that the user entered

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int maximumNumber = Math.Max(num1, num2);
    int minimumNumber = Math.Min(num1, num2);

    MessageBox.Show (maximumNumber);
}
```

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtbxnum1.Text);
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtbxnum1.Text);

            int maximumNumber = Math.Max(num1, num2);
            int minimumNumber = Math.Min(num1, num2);

            MessageBox.Show(maximumNumber.ToString());


        }

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

```
string txtbxnum1 = Int32.Parse(num1);
```

`Int32.Parse` takes in a string and returns an `int`. However, you're trying to assign it to a `string`. It should be

```
int txtbxnum1 = Int32.Parse(num1);
```

Assigning an array like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[2] {0,1};
```

simply creates a new array that can hold two integers and prefills them with the values `0` and `1`. This isn't what you want to do. As far as I can tell, you don't even need to use arrays here unless you're using it somewhere else in your code.

You can find the `Max` and `Min` values by using methods in the `Math` class.

```
int minimumValue = Math.Min(txtbxnum1,txtbxnum2);
int maximumValue = Math.Max(txtbxnum1,txtbxnum2);
```

You can find out more about the Math class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx).